# svn commit current state as 'version'

Tags: svn

is there a way to store the full state of a repository as a certain 'version'. my repository contains a c++ project and I would like to back it up in subversion on a daily basis and then be easily able to revert to e.g. a version 3 days ago, or switch easily between versions. Is that possible?
If not, could I achieve that with git/bitbucket?

Comment: That's exactly how svn works. It acts as a time machine and helps you save the state and switch between the states if you need. Have you read any help topics or documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to "back it up", you can put your working copy back to the state of a certain day easily by using a date instead of a revision number. For example, to go back a week from now:

```
svn up -r {2017-02-03}
```

Then go back to current state simply with:

```
svn up
```

If you want to directly manifest these states, you could create a new tag each day - in Subversion these are simple copies, so for example at the end of today you'd do:

```
svn cp [REPO-URL]/trunk [REPO-URL]/tags/2017-02-10
```

Assuming you've done this for at least a week, you could go back:

```
svn switch [REPO-URL]/tags/2017-02-03
```

And go back to current again:

```
svn switch [REPO-URL]/trunk
```

As the commenter noted, these are fairly basic principles of SCM software. I'd stongly suggest reading up on the matter - in the case of Subversion, there's the excellent ["red bean book"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), which is available online and for free.